# Can't set permissions for var/www

Tags: 14.04

I have installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I cant set read write permission for var/www folder. I have tried all the examples shownl. Any one please help..

Answer (score 2):

Hi try the following from terminal

```
1. sudo chmod 774 /var
2. sudo chmod 774 /var/www/
```

then check if you can now access the folder

Comment: @mchid lol sorry seemed I miss typed there my bad ;-) thanks for your input

Comment: also, you may need to add the user to the group to allow access

Comment: Thank you for your reply..... Its worked... but i cant access any files in it... It shows Not found error.

Comment: Is the html folder in the www folder